# Shuffle array of object based on given number and adjust elements

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
   let arr = [ { id:1 ,name : 'firstName' , columnNumber:1},
               { id:2 ,name : 'lastName' , columnNumber:2}
               { id:3 ,name : 'MiddleName' , columnNumber:3},
               { id:4 ,name : 'OfficeNo' , columnNumber:4},
               { id:5 ,name : 'CustomerName' , columnNumber:5}]
```

So now I want to assign id 3 to ColumnNumber 1 so that I will get

```
          let arr = [ { id:3,name : 'MiddleName' , columnNumber:1},
               { id:1,name : 'firstName' , columnNumber:2}
               { id:2 ,name : 'lastName' , columnNumber:3},
               { id:4 ,name : 'OfficeNo' , columnNumber:4},
               { id:5 ,name : 'CustomerName' , columnNumber:5}]
```

Comment: What have you tried and what has your research shown?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always try to add what you have tried to get better response to your question. It is helpful for your learning and also to the people trying to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, I agree on comments, please try to explain your trouble and what you have done so far. But I believe you're looking for something like that.

```js
let arr = [{ id:1 ,name : 'firstName' , columnNumber:1},{ id:2 ,name : 'lastName' , columnNumber:2},{ id:3 ,name : 'MiddleName' , columnNumber:3},{ id:4 ,name : 'OfficeNo' , columnNumber:4},{ id:5 ,name : 'CustomerName' , columnNumber:5}];

function moveElement(arr, from, to){
  let temp = arr[from];
  arr.splice(from, 1);
  arr.splice(to, 0, temp);
  for(let i=Math.min(from,to); i<=Math.max(from,to); i++){
    arr[i]["columnNumber"] = i+1;
  }
}

moveElement(arr, 2, 0);

console.log(arr);
```

Besides, if you dont store column number in your object array (because its not a different thing from its index), you wont need the for loop at all.

Comment: tried with different combinations this solution is did not give me expected result

Comment: I believe it should give you the expected results. Can you share your result?

Comment: just called u r function by passing different values  -    moveElement(arr, 2, 5);

Comment: I don't think there is an element with index 5 for this example. I implemented a function for this example just to give you an idea about your question, I didn't put all the conditions needed. Please don't expect people to write your code, try to understand the approach here.